# TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable I don't know how to handle this

Tags: python, json

I want to parse this dictionary to a json file. I saw lots of solutions on google and on this forum but none of them worked.

```
import json


standardcategories = {
                "unnecessary": 0,
                "unimportant": 1,
                "important": 2,
                "crucial": 3,
                "fixed": 4
}
with open('categories.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(f,standardcategories,indent=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
json.dump(standardcategories, f, indent=2)
```

Instead of:

```
json.dump(f, standardcategories, indent=2)
```

Notice that I've interchanged the order of `f` and `standardcategories`